# How to propagate ondragover event happening over an iframe, up to the parent div containing it?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, dom-events

How do I propagate a ondragover event, happening on an iframe back up to the parent div which contains the iframe? I have associated ondragover and ondrop event handlers to parent div. I create an iframe programatically in the ondrop event handler, when something is dragged over the div. Next time around if something is dragged over this iframe, I want to reduce the size of this iframe to half, to create space for new iframe creation. That new iframe would be created in ondrop event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got a solution to it. Placed a transparent empty div inside the parent div of same width and height as the parent div, and set the z-order to 2 (the z-order should be greater than iframe's z-order). Basically this arrangement would overlay the iframe, and as a result, events now get bubbled up to parent div.

Comment: That works as long as it's ok for the iframe to not receive mouse events.  The iframe will not be clickable.

Comment: Yes, I don't wish to capture mouse events on iframes. To make the iframe clickable, I change the z-order of the transparent div to -1 after the drag drop operation finishes. Setting the z-order of transparent div to 2 at the beginning of drag operation makes my parent div capture all events pertaining to drop operations, and then changing the z-order of transparent div to -1 at the end of drop operation, allows the iframe to be clicked.